# Download/Update Google Spreadsheet (Python)

Tags: python, google-sheets

Good morning,

I am using Python-script to upload a file on Google Drive.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from apiclient import errors

import io
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

folder_id = 'MyID021847773466366' 

try :
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()

if not creds or creds.invalid:
    print("make new storage data file ")
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = client.OOB_CALLBACK_URN
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
            if flags else tools.run(flow, store)

DRIVE = build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

FILES = (
    ('CVE.xlsx'),
)


folder_id = 'ds8d7s8d78s7d8s7d8'

file_metadata  = {
    'name': 'CVE.xlsx',
    'parents': [folder_id],
    'mimeType': None

}
media = MediaFileUpload('CVE.xlsx',
                        mimetype=None,
                        resumable=True)

file = DRIVE.files().insert(body=file_metadata , media_body=media,fields='id').execute()
```

It works fine wie "V2". If I open my uploaded file with Google-Spredsheats I get a second file:

```
CSV.xlsx -- 5MB (uploaded file)
CSV.xlsx -- --  (new file)
```

My problem: I want to modified a file online and download it automatically on my machine:

```
file_id = 'd56d5d5d5d5d5d'
request = DRIVE.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.FileIO('CVE.xlsx', 'wb')
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

I also have a code to upload it after modified on my machine by filter or something like that:

```
file_id = 'd56d5d5d5d5d5d'

file = DRIVE.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()
updated_file = DRIVE.files().update(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=file,
        media_body=media).execute()
```

But this works only with the file_id of the original file (uploaded 5MB file). As soon as I open the file with Google Spreadsheet, it does not work.

Error message for the download-code:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pydri.py", line 81, in
>   
>       status, done = downloader.next_chunk()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client_helpers.py", line 133, in
>   po sitional_wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 692, in
>   nex t_chunk
>       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self._uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.goo
>   gleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1_xJVvq3-hOGPPUJ4T3B8_Dz?alt=medi a
>   returned "File not found: 1_xJVvq3-hOGPPUJ4T3B8_Dz">"

Can somebody help me?

Comment: To export the file I used export_media. But How to upload my file and update the google spreadsheet file? With DRIVE.files().update I can only update a file, but not the google spreadsheet.